# Как перенести WordPress сайт на локалку?

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress, его надо перенести на локалку для дальнейших изменений. Не подскажете, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите [Local Lightning](https://getflywheel.com/layout/product-updates/local-lightning/) на локальном компьютере в качестве веб-сервера.

Используйте плагин [Duplicator](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) для переноса сайта.